# Как передать функцию в структуру c++?

Tags: c++, struct

Хочу сделать функцию атрибутом структуры. Пробовал просто передать, но не получается

```
string helloWorld() {
    cout << "Hello, world";
}

void main()
{

};

struct first {
    string name = "Array";
    string hello = helloWorld;
};
```

Пишет ошибку "Не существует подходящего конструктора для преобразования из "std::string" в "std::basic_string < char  ..."

Comment: Вам в структуре нужен указатель на функцию https://metanit.com/cpp/tutorial/4.8.php . Или использовать класс-обертку `std::function<>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если действительно надо передавать функцию, то у нее другой тип, а не std::string. В современном C++ удобно использовать `std::function`, например:

```
#include <string>
#include <functional>

std::string helloWorld(int j) {
   std::cout << j;
   return "Hello, world";
}


struct first {
   std::string name = "Array";
   std::function<std::string(int)> hello = helloWorld;
};
```

'''